# Импорт данных csv и работа с ними в R

Tags: csv, r

Доброго времени суток форумчане. Не знаю каким образом считать данные из csv.
Имеем одну длинную строку вида "6;3619;13;3520;28;3483;42;3479;", где элементы попарно обозначают точку на координатной плоскости то есть x;y;x;y;x;y (для построения динамограммы), подскажите пожалуйста как правильно их считать, чтобы отрисовать динамограмму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt <- "6;3619;13;3520;28;3483;42;3479;"
dat <- read.table(text=txt,sep = ';',col.names = c('x','y'))

plot(dat)
lines(dat)
```